# Get the node.js install path from code

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to write a debugging framework for [node.js](http://nodejs.org) and am having a hard time figuring out how to get the full path to a core module file like `fs.js`.

I've heard it's in the `/lib` folder of the node installation, but I'd need to get this from the code in a consistent way for a variety of install situations (including windows).

I've tried taking a look at the `process` and `process.env` values for something like a node install path but can't see anything that immediately pops out at me.

Comment: you can look in `require.cache`, but there doesn't seem to be a direct mapping between the module name and the filename, ie `require('fs')` and `fs/index.js`

Comment: `require.cache` doesn't really help.  There is no guarantee that the file name represents an actual module; ie I could need to load `fsHelper.js` in the `fs` module.

Answer (score 15):

To find where the installed node executable is located you can look at the *[process.execPath](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_execpath)* which gives the absolute path to Node executable.

To find where a certain module is located you can use [require.resolve](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_require_resolve)(module);

However I think the global modules are not directly accessible from the filesystem as other regular modules since they seem to be cached somewhere within the executable.

Comment: I think `process.config.variables.node_prefix` has been better for getting the node executable path.  `process.env.PATH` is just my regular path variable and I think windows might actually use a `NODE_PATH`.  Also, just a quick node repl check of `require.resolve("fs")` would show you that that is of no help to me.

Comment: Like I said built in modules are cached somewhere within the executable. require.resolve will show module paths, but it won't work for nodes built in modules, since they don't have a path.