# Locate Running Node JS File

Tags: javascript, node.js, centos

i have running node js file in port 8888, but i have completely forget where is the location of that file when i using command 'ps ax | grep node' this is the result

```
1590 ?        Ssl    6:56 node-red
23685 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep node
```

How or what command i need to use to know this file location ?

i already try netstat command but that stil not reveale any information about the location.

this is netstat result

```
tcp        0      0 :::993                      :::*                        LISTEN      1842/dovecot
tcp        0      0 :::995                      :::*                        LISTEN      1842/dovecot
tcp        0      0 :::587                      :::*                        LISTEN      1856/exim
tcp        0      0 :::110                      :::*                        LISTEN      1842/dovecot
tcp        0      0 ::1:783                     :::*                        LISTEN      1876/spamd-dormant
tcp        0      0 :::143                      :::*                        LISTEN      1842/dovecot
tcp        0      0 :::8080                     :::*                        LISTEN      1590/node-red
tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      1929/httpd
tcp        0      0 :::465                      :::*                        LISTEN      1856/exim
tcp        0      0 :::21                       :::*                        LISTEN      1939/pure-ftpd (SER
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      1613/sshd
tcp        0      0 :::8888                     :::*                        LISTEN      1590/node-red
tcp        0      0 :::25                       :::*                        LISTEN      1856/exim
tcp        0      0 :::1883                     :::*                        LISTEN      1590/node-red
tcp        0      0 :::443                      :::*                        LISTEN      1929/httpd
```

**Updated question**

i want know where is the .js file location, not the executeable installed.

Comment: I think that that's what you want [https://superuser.com/questions/103309/how-can-i-know-the-absolute-path-of-a-running-process](https://superuser.com/questions/103309/how-can-i-know-the-absolute-path-of-a-running-process)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the node.js install path from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12714979/get-the-node-js-install-path-from-code)

Comment: @EvgenyKolyakov it didn't find my .js file, only my node executeable.

`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep 11 04:40 /proc/1590/exe -> /usr/local/bin/node`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The process.execPath property returns the absolute pathname of the
> executable that started the Node.js process.

For example:

'/usr/local/bin/node'

[process.execPath](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_execpath)